# How do you deploy Rserve on Heroku/Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, rserve

I want to deploy Rserve on Heroku, using the https://github.com/albertosantini/node-rio API wrapper. This works well on my local environment, but I have no clue how to deploy Rserve on Heroku. Could someone give me some instruction?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could find

https://github.com/virtualstaticvoid/heroku-buildpack-r

and to run node.js and R simultaneously

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi